# Как создать задачу в Битрикс24 с помощью python?

Tags: python, битрикс24

Мне нужно создать задачу в Битриксе, используя питон. Нашла библиотеку fast-bitrix24, там есть такой пример кода:

```
tasks = [
{
    'ID': d['ID'],
    'fields': {
        'TITLE': f'{d["ID"]} - {d["TITLE"]}'
    }
}
for d in deals]

b.call('crm.deal.update', tasks)
```

Однако я не поняла, что такое "crm.deal.update" и вообще не могу разобраться, как заставить это работать. Буду рада любой помощи!

Answer (score 0):

С помощью библиотеки requests можно создать.

```
body = {'fields':{'TITLE': 'title'}}
requests.post('webhook/tasks.task.add', json=body)
```

Или вам сделку надо обновить (crm.deal.update)?

Answer (score 0):

"crm.deal.update" - это метод rest api битрикса.
Посмотреть их можно здесь: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/